# Sending a .zip file in Django?

Tags: python, django, post, request, zip

I've been trying to send a .zip file via a POST request in Django but can't seem to work it out, here's what I've tried:

```
    def test_1(self):
        z = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip")
        file = (io.BytesIO(b"abcdef"), z)
        res = self.client.post("/upload/", {"zip":file}, content_type="multipart/form-data")
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

```
    def test_1(self):
        file = (io.BytesIO(b"abcdef"), "test.zip")
        res = self.client.post("/upload/", {"zip":file}, content_type="multipart/form-data")
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

```
    def test_1(self):
        z = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip")
        res = self.client.post("/upload/", {"zip":z}, content_type="multipart/form-data")
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

Every time I try to run the test it gets a status code of 400. Any ideas why? Without the `content_type` it gives me a `TypeError: Missing one required positional argument 'name'`. Here is the view:

```
def upload(request):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(request.FILES['zip'])
    for fi in z.namelist():
        dirname = os.path.splitext(fi)[0]  
        os.mkdir(dirname)  
        content = io.BytesIO(z.read(fi))
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(content)
        for i in zip_file.namelist():
            zip_file.extract(i, dirname)
    sum = os.path.getsize(dirname)
    shutil.rmtree(dirname)
    return HttpResponse(f"Success")
```

The program works fine when running it normally, just not when being tested which makes me think I'm not sending the .zip file correctly. Here's the HTML that works:

```
<form method="post" action="/upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="zip">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Trace:

```
#15 1.301 ======================================================================
#15 1.301 FAIL: test_return_file_size_when_zip_uploaded (program.test_usability.ProgramTestCase)
#15 1.301 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#15 1.301 Traceback (most recent call last):
#15 1.301   File "/usr/src/app/program/test_usability.py", line 13, in test_return_file_size_when_zip_uploaded
#15 1.301     self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
#15 1.301 AssertionError: 400 != 200
#15 1.301 
#15 1.301 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you share any traceback?

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: Can you try debug the view? Maybe use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` or if you have a debugger in your IDE? Just to see where the exceptions are happening, if any, or if it even reaches your view at all

Comment: Yup, so the request reaches the view however, it throws the error when request.FILES['zip'] is accessed. I printed the value of it and it's just empty.

Comment: Can you add that full traceback in the question as well